# Falha ao criar um site no iis 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, aplicação-web

Estou tentando publicar minha aplicação em um servidor windows server 2012 e IIS 8. Fiz o deploy dos arquivos para a devida pasta. No IIS, ao criar novo site e testar a conexão, obtenho a seguinte falha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como configurar corretamente o IIS para conseguir rodar minha aplicação que usa windows authentication?

Comment: Espero que você consiga uma boa resposta aqui, mas tente também o [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que usar um usuário com privilégios de leitura e escrita para `C:/inetpub`. Ou dar privilégios a seu usuário atual para essa pasta.

No IIS, antes de mandar testar a conexão você deve informar esse usuário: na opção chamada "Conectar Como...".

Com absoluta certeza isso é problema de falta de permissão a pasta citada.

Comment: Certo @Fernando! Se eu passar minhas credencias de usuário (que são as mesmas que eu usei para acessar o servidor e o IIS) no "conectar como" eu obtenho autorização ok no test connection. Porém isso ainda não me permite acessar meu site. Ao testar no browser com "Anonymous Authentication - Enabled" obtenho: **"Server Error in '/' Application. Access is denied."** e usando 'Windows Authentication - Enabled' tenho **"HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized"** Ou seja, problemas em relação a permissão ainda persistem...

Comment: Sei que isso foge um pouco a pergunta, mas tem ideia do que mais preciso verificar ou fazer @Fernando ?

Comment: @PFVictor, como você disse, isso já outra pergunta e outro problema, e me parece ser um problema na implementação da aplicação, se entendi o que você disse, mas sem mas detalhes se torna complicado tentar te ajudar nas escuras. Lhe recomendo criar uma outra questão detalhando seu problema e as dificuldades que está tendo, não se esqueça de ser o mais claro e objetivo possível e tente isolar seu problema, sinão ninguém poderá lhe ajudar e sua pergunta seria fechado como fora do escopo, por ser um problema especifico.